# How do you get Notepad++ to show separate lines when /r/n is in the text?

Tags: notepad++, newline, linefeed

I've pasted some XML into Notepad++.  The pasted text contains \r\n wherever a newline is supposed to occur.  However, Notepad++ is just showing the entire file on a single line.  It is as if it is ignoring the \r\n

So the text look like this:

```
Some stuff on one line\r\n     Some stuff that should be on another line\r\n
```

Instead of:

```
Some stuff on one line
Some stuff that should be on another line
```

Comment: See this http://superuser.com/questions/274509/how-to-display-r-n-as-new-line-in-notepad

to summarize:
Replace regexp \\r\\n with \n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the search mode in Notepad++ to Extended. Then, find and replace all the /r/n with an actual line break(\n). See: [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/34451/notepad-find-and-replace-string-with-a-new-line) for more information about this similar case. From what I found, you can get away with simply *\n*.

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and the Replace dialog will open.

1. Type `\\r\\n` in "Find what"
2. Type `\r\n` in "Replace with".
3. select search mode Extended (\r, \n, \t, \x..., \0)
4. click "Replace All"

Comment: That will achieve nothing. Did you mean a find what of `\\r\\n`?

Comment: I do not understand why you said it will achieve nothing.  It worked for me on version 7.9.5.  +1 to the poster

Answer (score 1):

Press *Ctrl+H* and the *Replace* dialog will open, then follow the steps:

1. type `\r\n` in "Find what".
2. type `\\\r\\\n` in "Replace with"
3. select search mode to Extended (`\r`, `\n`, `\t`, `\x`, ..., `\0`)
4. click *Replace* button
   It works for me to display `\r\n`.
   [image: see my screenshot]